# How to remove Unhandled Exception Error in the Java Code

Tags: java, exception

I am new to Java and trying my hands on the exception handling code. Everything was fine to me until I get **unhandled exception error**. Can anyone please help me to correct the code and tell my mistake so that I can never commit again?

**Exception Class** - Created this to retrieve message for different exceptions

```
 // Implement user defined exception classes 
class InvalidAgeException extends Exception{

public InvalidAgeException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

}
class InvalidJobProfileException extends Exception{

public InvalidJobProfileException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

}
class InvalidNameException extends Exception{

public InvalidNameException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

}
```

**Applicant Class** - Class to set and get attributes of Applicant

```
class Applicant {

private String name;
private String jobProfile;
private int age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
  
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
  
public String getJobProfile() {
     return jobProfile;
}
  
public void setJobProfile(String jobProfile) {
    this.jobProfile = jobProfile;
}
  
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
  
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

**Validator Class** - Class to check if the Applicant has a name or not

```
class Validator{
    //Implement your code here
            public boolean validateName(String name) throws Exception
            {
            if(getName().length()>0)
             {
            return true;
             }
            else{
            return false;
        }

}
    public boolean validateJobProfile(String jobProfile) throws Exception
   {
    if (getJobProfile().equalsIgnoreCase("Associate") || getJobProfile().equalsIgnoreCase("Clerk") || 
    getJobProfile().equalsIgnoreCase("Executive") || getJobProfile().equalsIgnoreCase("Officer"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
public boolean validateAge(int age) throws Exception
{
    if(getAge()>=18 && getAge()<=30)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
public void validate(Applicant applicant) throws Exception
{
    if(validateName(getName())==false)
    {
        throw new InvalidNameException("Invalid Name");
    }
    if (validateJobProfile(getJobProfile())==false)
    {
        throw new InvalidJobProfileException("Invalid job post");
    }
    if (validateAge(getAge())==false)
    {
        throw new InvalidAgeException("Invalid Age");
    }

}
}
```

**Tester Class** -  Main Class where objects of different classes are created

```
class Tester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    try {
        Applicant applicant= new Applicant();
        applicant.setName("Jenny");
        applicant.setJobProfile("Clerk");
        applicant.setAge(25);
        
        Validator validator = new Validator();
              
        validator.validate(applicant);
        System.out.println("Application submitted successfully!");
    } 
    catch (InvalidNameException|InvalidJobProfileException|InvalidAgeException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also, please make it a [MCVE]. This isn't minimal. And finally, include the error message in a way that it actually relates to the problematic code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method declares that it `throws Exception`. Thus, you have to actually catch `Exception`. If you only want to have to catch either of the three custom exceptions, you need to declare your method as only throwing those three via `throws InvalidNameException, InvalidJobProfileException, InvalidAgeException`

Plus, your `validateAge` is declared as throwing an exception, but never actually does throw anything.

Comment: Glad to see your instant response. But can you please see all the getters and setters inside the boolean methods are they correct? as the classes are aggregated.

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma If you have another question, you should ask another question. Though it sounds like your request would be better of at CodeReview SE.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods need to specify which exceptions they are actually throwing. At the moment you are simply writing that they throw the general `Exception`, which you then don't catch in your main.
Change

```
public void validate(Applicant applicant) throws Exception{...}
```

to

```
public void validate(Applicant applicant) throws InvalidNameException, InvalidJobProfileException, InvalidAgeException{...}
```

For the other methods you need to do it similarly.

Comment: ok i have edited the code as per your suggestion but can you please check all the getters and setters inside the methods. Are they correct? I'm little confused